# Fixed div according to page scroll

Tags: css, css-position

I am developing a store for a friend and I want to make the "ADD TO CART'S DIV" fixed when the users scrolls after it. As I am far from being a CSS expert I am facing problems with it.

I tried to use JS to add "position: fixed" to the div, but I cant do that because the div has a relative position and changing it do fixed mess up with all the div's elements

[this is the link](https://trendotrends.com/products/cat-eye-sunglasses)

and this is the div I want to make fixed (the div id is rightcol):
[image: and this is the div I want to make fixed]

I would also want to make the div stop right before footer

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd need to use `position: fixed;` and `top:0; right: 0;` on the container div. This should position it wherever you want when adding stop before the footer would require changing the css property in javascript using an event at a certain window position.

Comment: Here is how it is: https://zckp5iw9gc2imykz-7669317690.shopifypreview.com/products/cat-eye-sunglasses The fixed position messed up with the container's width, how to fix that? And what would be the best way to make it stop before footer? Add/remove class with JS? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use this property to make div sticky on scroll

```
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
```

[image]

the header is your website is also sticky. you can use the same properties it works

Comment: In which div should I add these properties? I added in the #rightcol div and it didnt make any changes. Chrome also said "position: -webkit-sticky;" is an invalid property. Thanks!

Comment: you have used position fixed property for the header to stick at the top. so you can use position:fixed for this also. this code works completely fine      #rightcol{ position: fixed; width: 30%; right: 50px; z-index: 9; background: #fff;
 }. add these properties for id rightcol

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position sticky`. sticky element works as fixed element with respect to its parent element. It will serve as fixed in the space provided by its parent.

So in order for your project. You need to restructure your html in such a way that sticky element should get enough space to behave as fixed element in that region.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replie! I cant restructure my html, because its a premade theme for a ecommerce platform. I tried to make the two containers siblings but it lost a lot of functionality of the ecommerce platform. Here is how it is right now: https://zckp5iw9gc2imykz-7669317690.shopifypreview.com/products/cat-eye-sunglasses Any way to make it stop right before footer?

Comment: We can do this by js only then. You can apply `on scroll` event by JS